# GX 15 U6 Java - OpenAPI (re)generation

Tags: genexus

I am exposing some REST services and GX is generating the OpenAPI document - very cool.  I had one or more objects that I exposed early on that I decided not to expose, but those objects are still in the OpenAPI document (default.yaml).  The only way I have found to get rid of those old 'artifacts' is to Rebuild All (which takes 3 hours).

Is there a way to force the regeneration of the default.yaml file without doing a Rebuild All?  If not, can this be added somewhere as an option?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a hack you can do.
Go to `<KB folder>\GXRESTSPC\<Version folder>` and delete the .json files from the previously exposed objects.
Also, go to you `<environment>\web` folder and delete the `default.yaml` file.

This should do it.

Comment: Hey Sebastian!  Good to hear from you and hope you and your family are doing well.  Thanks for the tip - I did not know about the first part.

Do you think something could be added to the IDE to handle this?

Comment: Hey Scott, yes, your question triggered an issue. We'll take a look at a better way to achieve this. Thanks and stay safe.